# How to Fix Textures Glitching When Rendering in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, texturing, eevee-render-engine

When rendering a short scene in Eevee, the textures on some moving objects seem to glitch on an occasional frame. [image: Depiction of glitches when rendering]

Some of the glitches (right side of picture) appear as black or darkened shapes (often triangular) flashing up and down the shape. In other places (left side of picture) the texture is simply garbled/distorted slightly.

Here's what I know:

- The glitches do not appear when the object is not moving.
- The glitches only appear when viewing the scene through the camera.
  (They don't appear when just looking at it through the viewport.)
- Only objects that have movement animation have the glitches.
- These glitches only appear in the Eevee rendering engine.
- Camera movement reduces the presence of the glitches to almost none, but a few small ones are
  still visible.
- Lighting doesn't have an affect on the severity/presence of the glitches.
- Objects are parented to the main cylinder and the whole thing is keyframed for rotation. No armatures involved.

Here's what I've tried:

- Checked for duplicated faces/vertices and used "Merge by distance" several times. No
  duplicate faces found.
- Tried using shade smooth
- Reloaded and created new textures for all objects with glitches.
- Restarted Blender and reopened the project.
- Looked around and haven't seemed to find anybody else with this exact problem.

Here's a short video clip of what the issue looks like in the context of the animation: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PS5izT1E7O6NyF37xHtGmZy1Pddbn4P5/view?usp=sharing

Here's the blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11o9RnYaHy579Bl37g5PWNp3WSuk3HoZV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi and welcome to BSE. I think you should upload your blend file or take a screenshot of the materials. Also the modifiers and/or animation/armatures used here.

Comment: I added the blend file to the question text. Just for clarification, there are no armatures used, just the objects parented to one of the merlons on top of the tower. The origin of that merlon was then moved down to the base of the tower so it'd rotate on that origin. If there's an easier/more acceptable way of achieving that animation I'm open to doing that too.